# Magento js and css changes not reflect

Tags: javascript, php, css, magento

I had problem that i added custom java script its included but when i changes its contents it doesn't effect. it runs older java script file. since i cleared cache. i deleted every folder of /var/ also. but still it runs older java script code. while i see it in uploaded file also it shows updated code but using URL of that java script in browser it shows old code.
I flushed magento cache storage. flushed cache of css/javascript also.

In case if any guy have solution let me know.

Thanks in advance.

EDITED

Same problem with css also. Changes doen't reflect. cleared cache a lot of times from back-end as well as cleared var folder also.

Comment: Are you sure that drops Magento cache?

Comment: 100 of times i deleted cache and session folder from var. and i cleared from back-end also. i tried by deleting that file fromserver also. still it shows file with old code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server probably have header information asking browsers to cache static files like JS/CSS. It is likely that your browser is still caching the old CSS files. One way to check if it is indeed the browser and not say accidentally editing the wrong CSS file is by enabling and disabling (only go one way to check) the CSS file merge. By doing so you are forcing the browser to fetch for a whole new file - essentially bypassing caching.

You may also want to take a look at our CSS/JS Versioning extension which includes automatic refresh of the file name hash based on CSS/JS file timestamps (sensitive to editing and changes) http://extensions.activo.com/css-and-javascript-versioning.html

Comment: I had the same problem and with your "forcing the browser cache" answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared your local browser cache on your workstation?

Often, CSS and JavaScript can stick mightily and no matter now much you flush Magento caching on the server, the workstation browser never requests and downloads the new script. These are static files, a change in file date doesn't trigger browser reload, only complete removal from the browser cache does.

Usually CTL-F5 about three times will do it, otherwise you have to go into the web browser setups and flush browser cache there.

Also, if you're using JavaScript/CSS Merge, you need to click the button on the Cache Management page to **Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache** as well.

The only other place things can gum up is if you're running APC cache, you may need to flush it as well so the block caching for the head can refresh. This only matters if you changed the script and CSS file names, which you probably haven't, so it likely doesn't matter.